# Perform append operations without using the id element in java script

Tags: javascript, html

I want to see if there is a way to define the second div without defining an ID for the element or without using an attribute, and perform the append operation inside it, for example, to say that the p element should be appended inside the second div without using id And any other attribute, let's mention the second div.

- More details are in the code *

  ```js
   function createEle() {
          var c = document.createElement('p');
          // In this section, I want to point to that div and use append without using an ID or any other   attribute
          return ?
        }
        createEle();
  ```

  ```html
      <section>
        <div>
          <div>I want the p tag to be appended in this div</div>
        </div>
      </section>
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a selector string instead, with only tag names. Eg `section > div > div` will select the nested div (it'll select a div which is a child of a div, which is a child of a section):

```js
function createEle() {
  const inner = document.querySelector('section > div > div');
  inner.appendChild(document.createElement('p')).textContent = 'foo';
}
createEle();
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <div>I want the p tag to be appended in this div</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you dear friend. Is there another way or the only way to do this?

Comment: That's the most concise way. I guess you could also select the section (or even the `<body>` or something), then navigate through `.children[]` indicies to get there.

Comment: Which method do you introduce as a better, more efficient and better known method?

Comment: Definitely `querySelector`, since it's more concise and easier to understand at a glance, it maps exactly with CSS selector strings, which everyone should be familiar with already

Comment: Thank you dear friend for your help. Good luck